Filling NaN in dataframe column based on groupby dataframe value
I want to impute values to replace NaNs in a dataframe. The dataframe contains Hour, Location and multiple numeric columns associated with speeds, times etc.
In each of the numeric columns containing NaNs, I want to replace the missing value with the average value for the hour and locationcode for that column.
EG The duration in Row 2 would be given the average value of the hour 0, Location BG values (3.15,3.18, 3.22) etc



Hour
Location
Duration




0
BG
3.15


0
BG
NaN


0
WH
3.12


0
BG
3.18


0
BG
3.22


1
WH
43.1


1
WH
NaN


1
BG
42.5


1
WH
38.4


1
BG
37.8



I assign
df_mean = df.groupby(['Hour','Location']).mean(numeric_only=True)

with the intention of using this dataframe of means to be a source for the replacment vlue but haven't found any success in solving my issue.

df['Duration'] = df['Duration'].fillna(
    df.groupby(['Hour', 'Location'])['Duration'].transform('mean')
)


Try using groupby and transform:
df['Duration'] = df.groupby(['Hour', 'Location']).transform(lambda x: x.fillna(x.mean()))

Output:
   Hour Location   Duration
0     0       BG   3.150000
1     0       BG   3.183333
2     0       WH   3.120000
3     0       BG   3.180000
4     0       BG   3.220000
5     1       WH  43.100000
6     1       WH  40.750000
7     1       BG  42.500000
8     1       WH  38.400000
9     1       BG  37.800000


You can Group by Hour and Location and calculate the mean` for each group
df_mean = df.groupby(['Hour', 'Location']).transform('mean')
df_filled = df.fillna(df_mean)
print(df_filled)

output
     Hour Location   Duration
0     0       BG   3.150000
1     0       BG   3.183333  
2     0       WH   3.120000
3     0       BG   3.180000
4     0       BG   3.220000
5     1       WH  43.100000
6     1       WH  40.750000  
7     1       BG  42.500000
8     1       WH  38.400000
9     1       BG  37.800000

